# How to check if a user is an ADMINISTER in Jenkins via Groovy Script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

How do I check if **all authenticated users** on a Jenkins instance have *Administrative privileges*?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following on your Jenkins instance's groovy script console

> http://jenkins-url/script

```
Jenkins.instance.authorizationStrategy.hasPermission("authenticated",Jenkins.ADMINISTER);
```

Comment: It gives me an error: `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy.hasPermission() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, hudson.security.Permission) values: [authenticated, Permission[class hudson.model.Hudson,Administer]]`